# Java Statement.executeUpdate(sql) not working when executeQuery(sql) works

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a wierd behavior in a Java application.
It issues simple queries and modifications to a remote MySQL database. I found that queries, run by `executeQuery()` work just fine, but inserts or delete to the database run through `executeUpdate()` will fail.

Ruling out the first thing that comes to mind: the user the app connects with has correct privilledges set up, as the same INSERT run from the same machine, but in DBeaver, will produce the desired modification.

Some code:

#### Connection creation

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

#### Problematic part:

```
Statement parentIdStatement = connection.createStatement();
String parentQuery = String.format(ProcessDAO.GET_PARENT_ID, parentName);
if (DEBUG_SQL) {
      plugin.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, parentQuery);
}
ResultSet result = parentIdStatement.executeQuery(parentQuery);
result.first();
parentId = result.getInt(1);
if (DEBUG_SQL) {
      plugin.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, parentId.toString()); // works, expected value
}

Statement createContainerStatement = connection.createStatement();
String containerQuery = String.format(ContainerDAO.CREATE_CONTAINER, parentId, myName);
if (DEBUG_SQL) {
      plugin.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, containerQuery); // works when issued through DBeaver
}
createContainerStatement.executeUpdate(containerQuery); // does nothing
```

#### "DAOs":

```
ProcessDAO.GET_PARENT_ID = "SELECT id FROM mon_process WHERE proc_name = '%1$s'";
ContainerDAO.CREATE_CONTAINER = "INSERT INTO mon_container (cont_name, proc_id, cont_expiry, cont_size) VALUES ('%2$s', %1$d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NULL)";
```

I suspect this might have to do with my usage of `Statement` and `Connection`.
This being a lightweight lightly-used app, I went to simplicity, so no framework, and no specific isntructions regarding transactions or commits.

Comment: how about we see some of your code first

Comment: "[...] inserts or delete to the database [...] will fail." And what does that mean? This problem description is far too vague.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages while running executeUpdate()? please post here.
If you maintaining any transactions, check that configuration twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, this code was just fine. It worked today.

**To answer the question: where to look first in a similar case (SELECT works but UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE does not)**

If rights are not the problem, then there is probably a lock on the table you try to modify. In my case, someone left with an uncommited transaction open.

Proper SQL exceptions logging (which was suboptimal in my case) will help you figure it out.